# Photon and MetaMask Websocket are conflicting in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, metamask, photon, unity-webgl, photon-pun

Hello when I try to build my game with unity webGL I got this error :

Someone knows how i can resolve it ?

Plugin 'WebSocket.jslib' is used from several locations:
Assets/MetaMask/Plugins/Libraries/WebSocket/WebSocket.jslib would be copied to /WebSocket.jslib
Assets/Photon/PhotonLibs/WebSocket/WebSocket.jslib would be copied to /WebSocket.jslib
Please fix plugin settings and try again.

UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultPluginImporterExtension:CheckFileCollisions (string,string[])
UnityEditorInternal.PluginsHelper:CheckFileCollisions (UnityEditor.BuildTarget,string[])
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
Unity.Play.Publisher.Editor.PublisherBuildProcessor:OpenBuildGameDialog (UnityEditor.BuildTarget) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.connect.share@4.2.3/Editor/PublisherBuildProcessor.cs:178)
Unity.Play.Publisher.Editor.PublisherWindow:OnWebGLBuildTargetSet () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.connect.share@4.2.3/Editor/PublisherWindow.cs:748)
Unity.Play.Publisher.Editor.PublisherWindow:OnCreateABuildClicked () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.connect.share@4.2.3/Editor/PublisherWindow.cs:509)
Unity.Play.Publisher.Editor.PublisherWindow/<>c__DisplayClass75_0:b__0 () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.connect.share@4.2.3/Editor/PublisherWindow.cs:627)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

renmaing the websocket, but that creates more errors

Answer (score 0):

you have to rename both the websocket.cs and websocket.jslib file. In my case I renamed both as websockets.cs and websockets.jslib and it worked fine for me.